# Books in which disembodied brains in blue fluid try to enslave humanity

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been trying to identify a book with the following plot points:

- Humans hold part of the universe. A core group of disembodied brains in cans attempted to enslave all of humanity but only have a portion. The brain cans can fly spaceships, have robot bodies, etc.
- Of the first brain can people, one is a huge jerk who makes people build big monuments, one is a talented tactician, one woman brain left the group…
- There’s a planet of Amazon-like women who have mental powers and are able to liquidate the brains.
- One of the Amazon-like women is married to a successful merchant; their daughter is not mentally talented, but is wicked smart and goes to work with another guy to build weapons.
- Some disembodied brains rose above the fray to become wise, neutral parties; they have monk-like people who tend to them.

I read this about seven years ago when my library moved sites and borrowing history was lost! I do not remember anything about the cover. I do remember that the story takes place on the human side and the brain side, and that there are managers of the workers enslaved by brains and one of them helps revolt against them… and a hundred other little things. I do not remember when it was published, but I think it’s a fairly mainstream series; I don’t read a ton of SFF.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: About seven years ago when my library moved sites and borrowing history was lost! I do not remember anything about the cover :( I do remember that the story takes place on the human side and the brain side, and that there are managers of the workers enslaved by brains and one of them helps revolt against them… and a hundred other little things. I do not remember when published - but I think it’s a fairly mainstream series, I don’t read a ton of SFF

Comment: Another thing I remember - the not so good looking daughter of the main mental Amazon woman goes to work for the scientist weapon maker and he steals all her ideas because he’s a Dick, and later in the books she discovers her mental powers and makes herself super hot

Comment: Thank you for reinforcing my determination never to read a book by Brian Herbert.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah, I read all of Frank Herbert's Dune books and was excited when I heard Brian Herbert had supposedly discovered notes for the 7th book and was going to write it. But then he wrote prequels first, and managed to kill any interest I had in more Dune books within a couple of them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This sounds like it may be [Dune: the Butlerian Jihad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune:_The_Butlerian_Jihad), and/or the other novels in the Dune prequel series.

The books are set in our distant future, and the distant past of *Dune*. A group called the Titans converted themselves into "cymeks" - brains in canisters which could live indefinitely and be swapped between various powerful robot bodies - and conquered much of humanity, before themselves being usurped by entirely artificial beings.

> Of the first brain can people, one is a huge jerk who makes people build big monuments, one is a talented tactician, one woman brain left the group…

Their number included a general ([Agamemnon](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Agamemnon)) and a female dissident ([Hecate](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Hecate)); the monument-builder might be the robot [Erasmus](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Erasmus).

> There’s a planet of Amazon-like women who have mental powers and are able to liquidate the brains.

This would fit the Sorceresses of Rossak, precursors to the Bene Gesserit, who have psychic powers usable only by women, which can destroy cymeks.

> One of the Amazon-like women is married to a successful merchant; their daughter is not mentally talented, but is wicked smart and goes to work with another guy to build weapons.

[Norma Cenva](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Norma_Cenva/XD) is a daughter of a sorceress who apprentices to an inventor, marries a merchant, invents some of the setting's most fundamental technology, and is robbed of the credit for it.

> Norma Cenva was considered a failure by her mother, Zufa Cenva, because she was born a malformed dwarf. This was partially due to the strange chemicals on Rossak, the same reason why Sorceresses like her mother were so powerful.

> Norma was almost pitied by her mother while the former lived on Rossak. Meanwhile her adoptive father (and future husband) Aurelius Venport helped her continue her fascination and meddling with higher-order mathematics arranging for her to become an assistant to Tio Holtzman.

> She cared little that Holtzman took credit for much of her work. Nevertheless, her innovations would prove indispensable to humanity in the war against the thinking machines known as the Butlerian Jihad.

From your comments:

> Another thing I remember - the not so good looking daughter of the main mental Amazon woman goes to work for the scientist weapon maker and he steals all her ideas because he’s a Dick, and later in the books she discovers her mental powers and makes herself super hot

> While on a spaceflight, the Titan Xerxes captured her and tortured her for hours while many neo-cymeks watched. The event triggered latent mental powers, and caused her soostone pendant to fuse with her. The ultimate result was that she gained amazing powers to control her molecular structure and utilize formidable new prescient abilities. With just a thought, she killed Xerxes and the neo-cymeks. With massive amounts of mental power at her fingertips, Norma found herself in connection with her maternal bloodline leading off into the far distant past. Using their forms as a template, she then transformed her body from an unappealing dwarf-like being into a woman of great elegance and beauty.

Comment: I tried not to learn anything about the _Dune_ prequels, because I knew it would make me mad, but holy heck, this sounds _awful_.  "Agamemnon"?  "Sorceresses of Rossak"?

Comment: @DougWarren wait until you find out who his son is...

Comment: @DougWarren they are as bad as you think; don't do it unless you are a masochist locked in a room with no other reading material.

Comment: @DougWarren I only read them because I’m not a quitter and I believe in being thorough about with all things.

Comment: @DougWarren how is that any different to the main line novels? The main characters are named Atreides, so why is Agamemnon surprising? Agamemnon is known as "Agamemnon Atreides" since he is the son of Atreus.

Comment: My God.. Good thing I managed to avoid the Brian stuff so far. Now I'm certain I'll never want to read it. Note to self: Run search over the collection of ebooks I gathered over the last 20 years (to read when I'm retired and have time) and delete everything that has Brian Herbert on it.

Comment: "her adoptive father (and future husband)" ... ok.

Comment: @Doug Warren The names are fair enough, I think - the Titans are all using historical/mythical aliases, so you have Agamemnon, Hecate, Xerxes, etc. It's not like someone thousands of years in the future named their kid Agamemnon and he grew up to be a conqueror; it was a deliberately self-chosen identity. The rest... I read the first prequel when given it as a well-meaning gift, wasn't inclined to read more, and researching this answer bore out that decision. Classic prequel disease in compressing the Jihad, the Atreides/Harkonnen feud, and space folding into one handful of characters.

Answer (score 4):

Dang it I’m an idiot… thinking of the Butlerian Jihad :( convinced myself I wasn’t in the Duniverse… the Mental Powered women were the sorceresses of Rossak, the protagonist Serena Butler, the core group of disembodied brains were The Titans led by Agamemnon. Tio Holtzmann was the jerk store of an invented, Norma Cenva is the future to be hot sorceress.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining/naming the things that you mention in the question.

Comment: You could just select the other answer...